# Auto switch user to mobile version of the site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile-phones

I have a setup a redirect so any body on a mobile device get automatically transferred to the mobile version of the site. (See below - .htaccess file) But it suddenly occurred to me that some people may actually want to visit the main site (e.g on an iphone or ipad) Is there a way can somehow set a variable when a link is click is clicked (and kept for that session) and still allow of the .htaccess to control the redirect?

if it helps we are using `jquery mobile` and `php`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have done before is use `mod_rewrite` to also set a cookie:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !FULLSITE=yes
### Your current conditions...
RewriteRule (.*) http://m.yoursite.com/? [R,L]
```

And I set the cookie `FULLSITE` whenever the user actually clicks the "view full site" link from the mobile site.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Any reason you dont just use a server-side User-Agent sniff combined with a cookie? I would also seriously consider not automatically sending iPad users to a mobile version - they have a full-featured browser and plenty of space to view your page as a user in a traditional web browser would see it